# Custom Build for an Eclipse RCP app

Tags: eclipse, ant, rcp

I would like to integrate into the build process the following:
- Remove all the jrxml files in the source.
- Process plugin jar with a proguard config file.

### This is what i have tried so far

Leaving intact the rest of the "Eclipse Export Wizard" process.

I have tried to enable the 'custom build' check in the 'build' tab of the plugin and got a "no build.xml found try disabling..." then disabled it, tried again, copied the build.xml, and unchecked the 'custom build' and tried again, got an error:

```
C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\compile.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\project\build.xml:245: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\project\build.xml:206: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\project\build.xml:245: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\project\build.xml:206: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Tried running the build.xml as ant and i got a no java_home found, seted up the java_home and the build.xml works, but the Eclipse Export Wizard still got the same problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do this,

1. You need to have uncheck the 'custom build' on the 'build' tab of
   your build.properties.
2. Then right click the build.properties / PDE Tools / Create Ant Build file (this will generate a build.xml)
3. Then you can check the 'custom build'

And that's all folks... you will have a build.xml that you can modify (with this i could add ant tags to ignore the *.jrxml and integrate proguard with ant)
One detail is that you might need to change the absolute and relative paths to ${eclipse.home}  ${java.home}

Comment: Ah, thank you. Every other tutorial feels the need to complicate this.